# Displaying dialog for progress steps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

I'm a fresh IOS dev beginner, I don't know the whole terminology yet (between sheet, modal, dialog, view, ...)

### Context

I have a button that launchs a serie of actions that will take a certain time (maybe 2 or 3 seconds)

I would like to show a pretty dialog with a progess bar (certainly `UIProgressView`) and a text showing each steps one by one.

The user should not be able to do anything while processing, and the dialog should close itself when done.

### Question

Which approach should I use ?

I'm not asking for any code but simply which techniques, widgets should I use.
So I'll be able to google search with right terms :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Custom `UIActivityIndicator` is the thing you would like to use.

Why not using the already made control for that: https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD

Hope this will lessen your work.

Comment: This seems quite exactly what I'm searching :)

Comment: I also saw [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD), not sure which one I'm going to use yet

Answer (score 1):

There are many opensources projects available at [www.cocoacontrols.com](http://www.cocoacontrols.com). You can search for 'activity' and you can use any project from there, respecting the use terms of course. I use the SVProgressHUD.